# Kubernetes using Loadbalancer or Pod to execute only once and restart?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have a service that runs on port 8080 through a pod. I have a load balancer pointing to 10+ instances of this pod/service. It seems like under heavy load, the load balancer tries to use the same pod but the port is not available and the request fails. Once the service first service attaches to the port, the port binds causing problems for the 2nd attempt.

I would like to setup a deployment in which only uses a pod once (round robin maybe?) and assigns any subsequent requests for that service to a new pod. I can't seem to find a way to configure this, I see in JOBS, I might be able to configure a single use POD, but I need it as a service so that multiple requests are handle, just on their own unique POD.

I am currently using minikube and would like to deploy under that at the moment if it makes a difference.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: engine-deployment-e
  labels:
    app: engine-e
spec:
  replicas: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: engine-e 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: engine-e
    spec:
      containers:      
      - name: engine-e 
        image: s-medium-e  
        imagePullPolicy: Never        
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
          name: encrypt
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: engine-service-e
spec:
  selector:
    app: engine-e
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      name: e
      port: 30003
      targetPort: 8081
      nodePort: 30001
```

Comment: A Kubernetes Service will normally round-robin or otherwise distribute requests across its pods.  How are you actually connecting to it and sending load?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu "nc -N <ip>" to fire data at the service. I am not firing them fast (manual) but I am still seeing that the TCP request seems to go to a pod that hasn't terminated and reset at times. It is intermittent. It would be good to be able to tell the load balancer to only use the pod once until it terminates.